# How to change the scale of a two-port

Tags: circuitikz, tikzscale

I'm a beginner at drawings in Tikz and I was making a diagram for a report, and a little problem came up:
I need to change the scale of a **twoport**, I tried to do the following, but it hasn't worked...

```
(2,3) to [twoport,>, t=$\frac{\pi}{2}$, scale=0.7] (2,1) {}
```

Comment: It is also possible to change the size using \tikzset, but you would have to know the names of the dimensions (e.g. bipoles/twoport/width) and change all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In this site you would help us to help you by providing a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that demonstrates your problem and we can test on this without the need of typing all the needed code just to make your code compile-able. If the problem is that your code can't really compile and you can't do it due to errors, you should add the minimal code including the error you get and it is ok that it is not a "working" example, but it still has to be as minimal as possible. (Many times in this procedure of minimizing, you may discover the error without actually need our help.)

Here is a way but scaling to larger to get a visible image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[scale=2.7,transform shape] (2,3) to [twoport,>, t=$\frac{\pi}{2}$] (2,1) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]